# Help to ID tree and determine if it may be diseased

Tags: identification, trees, diseases, tree-care

would like to identify this tree and determine whether it is diseased or not. Thanks for any feedback. [image]

Comment: Looks like a mite infestation, something like erinose mite, but in order to ID, we need to see more of the plant - overall growth habit and the trunk, and whether it ever produces flowers or fruit.